# Scrambler with all zeros on input

Tags: ethernet, dsp, digital-communications, digital-modulation

Several communications standards use LFSR-based self-synchronizing (multiplicative) scramblers that are never reset to an initial state after initial power on. For example, 10GBASE-R Ethernet specifies the following scrambler:

[image: 10GBASE-R scrambler]

According to IEEE 802.3-2015 clause 49 "there is no requirement on the initial value for the scrambler", however it seems clear that the initial value should be non-zero, otherwise an all-idle signal will keep the output at zero for all eternity.

I have not done the math, but I suppose the circuit guarantees that an all-zero signal (idles) will never cause the LFSR to return to zero, given a non-zero state. However, it seems clear that there is always some pattern that will cause it to return to zero. If an all-zero signal follows, the output is essentially broken until another packet is sent, which can be never.

I realize that the scrambling technique is fundamentally imperfect since it can provide long series of zeros or ones, but isn't this situation more serious considering that it will potentially never resolve itself?

Comment: If you don't design your scrambler to the data stream it will eventually fail, yes.

Comment: @ThePhoton: You're right, I didn't think about that. I suppose this makes the question less specific.

Comment: my answer is the more general application of a scrambler or PRSG. One can choose a solution that permits all 1's or all 0's but not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Figure 49-7 in clause 49:

[image]

Idles are type of control code. When sending control codes in a block, you must start the block with a "block type field" to indicate the mix of control and data octets in the block. The value of the block-type field is nonzero.

Therefore the scrambler will never see a stream of all-zero's, even if idles are sent continuously.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the number of XOR or XNOR depending on register type Reset or Set on whether you choose odd parity or even parity feedback, and then you choose Inv or Non-Inv feedback.  So the initial condition of all 0 or 1 can be satisfied with one or the other implementation, while the complement is impossible

Answer (score 0):

The principles behind Linear Feedback Shift Registers mean that an n-bit LFSR will cycle through every value in 2^n once, except for one value: all zeroes for those with XOR feedback terms, all ones for those with XNOR feedback terms.

It is pretty straightforward to add detection logic to an LFSR that shifts in the required 1 or 0 if it has acquired its illegal value of all zeroes or all ones. An LFSR will never generate this illegal value for itself. It is conceivable that a circuit threatened by some great instability, such as supply noise or alpha particles, might consider this protection. But I doubt you'll come across an LFSR with such protection in a product any time soon.

Incidentally, it is tempting to imagine that using an LFSR to scramble a data stream by XORing could often produce long runs of 1s or 0s. In actuality, the odds against runs long enough to cause an ongoing problem are immense. You'll find text on the interweb covering this, I won't try to here. Have a look into 64/66b encoding, that's a good start.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the scrambler circuit shown in the question can return to all zeros. If you know the state of the register you can predict the value of the feedback to the leftmost XOR and always send the same value on the serial data input. This will fill the register with zeros. Of course the chance of this happening by chance is almost non-existent, and even if it happens anything but data blocks containing all zeros will cause the register to return to a non-zero value. As The Photon pointed out Idles are not all zeros after all and thus will not keep the register at zero.